# "No such file or directory" when I try to create '/artists/' + filename

Tags: python, file

All I'm trying to do is write a file to a certain directory. Here is my code. When I execute, I get "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/artists/Omar_Shariff.text' ", which seems odd since obviously it won't be available if I'm now creating it.

```
f = open('/artists/'+filename , 'w')
```

So artists is the folder within my home directory. I'm able to write to this home directory, if I just remove the '/artists/' part.

Comment: You are trying to write to a directory at the root of the file system. Take away the first fwd slash if you want to write into a directory relative to the current one.

Comment: Which is to say -- `/artists` means there needs to be a directory in `/`  named `artists`.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that `/artists/` is not the same as `artists/`. The first path leads to a folder that is a child of the root directory, and the second path leads to a relative directory - a child of the current directory which is called "arists".

A visualization:

```
-- root
  -- etc
  -- bin
  -- usr
  -- "/artists/"
  -- home
    -- your_user_name
      -- "artists/"
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `./` instead of `/`:

```
f = open('./artists/'+filename , 'w')
```

Or to be more precise, if the directory `artists` is in the same directory as your running script you can try this other method:

```
import os
current_script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
f = open(current_script_path + '/artists/'+filename , 'w')
```